# HTML and PHP mail application not sending

Tags: php, html, email, web

I trying to make an application form but it just won't work. I've been searching on the site to find some answers, but without luck. - I have tried several different scripts.

And the think is I'm using almost the same php script as my contact form but only with $mail, $subject and $message - and it is working just fine.

Here is my codes:

```
    <?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "IADDEDMYMAILHERE@hotmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter a subject");
$birthday = check_input($_POST['birthday']);
$cloths = check_input($_POST['cloths'], "Write your message");
$currentclub = check_input($_POST['currentclub'], "Klub");
$coachphone = check_input($_POST['coachphone'], "Indtast din træners telefonnummer");
$team = check_input($_POST['team'], "Indtast dit nuværende holds navn");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Du mangler motiveret ansøgning");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

name: $name
E-mail: $email
Birthday: $birthday
Cloths: $cloths
Currentclub: $currentclub
Clubranking: $clubranking
Coachphone $coachphone
Clubhis: $clubhis
Team: $team
Attention: $attention
Message: $message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $name, $birthday, $cloths, $currentclub, $clubranking, $coachphone, $clubhis, $team, $attention, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: kontakt.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

My HTML code:

```
 <form class="email" action="application.php" method="post">

        <div id="ansøgninger">
<h4>Name</h4> <input type="text" name="name">
<h4>Email</h4> <input type="text" name="email">
<h4>fødselsdag</h4> <input type="text" name="birthday">

<h4>Tøjstørrelse</h4>
<select name="cloths" size="1">
<option value="XS" name="cloths">XS</option>>
<option value="S" name="cloths">S</option>>
<option value="M" name="cloths">M</option>>
<option value="L" name="cloths">L</option>>
<option value="XL" name="cloths">XL</option>>
</select>

<h4>Nuværende klub</h4> <input type="text" name="currentclub">

<h4>Hvilken række spiller klubben i?</h4>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
<br />

<h4>Nuværende træners telefonnummer</h4> <input type="text" name="coachphone">

<h4>Klubhistorik</h4> <input type="text" name="clubhis">

<h4>udvalgt hold?</h4> <input type="text" name="team">

<h4>Ting vi skal være opmærksomme på?</h4> <input type="text" name="attention">

<h4>Type</h4>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Website Update</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">New Products</option>
</select>
<br />

<h4>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: were you able to send mail in your server before ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `mail` correctly:

```
mail($myemail, $name, $birthday, $cloths, $currentclub, $clubranking, $coachphone, $clubhis, $team, $attention, $message);
```

The manpage is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - you need to pass in the email address; the subject line; and the message; with a couple of optional parameters. You need to concatenate all your text into a single message variable, and pass that variable in, instead of each of the different values:

```
mail ($myemail, 'Subject', $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function takes 3 parameters like so

```
mail(to, subject, message)
```

You can add headers and additional parameters too.

change your `mail()` line to

```
mail($myemail, $email, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the documentation of mail function, 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail($myemail, $name, $birthday, $cloths, $currentclub, $clubranking, $coachphone, $clubhis, $team, $attention, $message);
```

the arguments you are passing in the `mail()` function are wrong...

you try writing 
`mail($myemail, $email, $message)`

Variable `$myemail` should store the email of the recipient and `$email` should have the subject stored in it, and $message should contain the message you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error looks to be with the use of your mail() php function, this function only takes a maximum of 5 parameters

```
mail($myemail, $name, $birthday, $cloths, $currentclub, $clubranking, $coachphone, $clubhis, $team, $attention, $message);
```

You appear to have included $name, $birthday, $cloths, $currentclub, $clubranking, $coachphone, $clubhis, $team, $attention, $message already inside your $message variable so no need to include these again in the mail function.

Your code should look something similar to:

```
$emailMessage = "
name: $name
E-mail: $email
Birthday: $birthday
Cloths: $cloths
Currentclub: $currentclub
Clubranking: $clubranking
Coachphone $coachphone
Clubhis: $clubhis
Team: $team
Attention: $attention
Message: $message
";

 mail($myemail, $subject, $emailMessage);
```

Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for the usage of the mail() function.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example code for mail ..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072751/write-the-email-code-for-upload-resume-in-contact-page-receive-the-email-in-php/20073275#20073275

**Send a simple email:**

```
<?php
$txt = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// Use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$txt = wordwrap($txt,70);

// Send email
mail("somebody@example.com","My subject",$txt);
?>
```

**Send an email with extra headers:**

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

**Send an HTML email:**

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```