# HTML Email with attachment styling issue

Tags: php

Following is my `$message` variable in which I did the inline styling for html email but the issue is email is sending along with attachement but styling is not applying and sends the entire code as it is. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue so the HTML Styled email being send?

```
$message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<img src="http://webi.com/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
    $message .= '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:1px solid #3A5896;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><img src='http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/uploads/gang.jpg' alt='PHP Gang' /></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan=2>";
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['fname']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['lname']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['address'] . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><I>PHPGang.com<br>Solve your problem. :)</I></td></tr>"; 
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

     // Now we'll build the message headers
      $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

 // Next, we'll build the message body note that we insert two dashes in front of the  MIME boundary when we use it
      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";

      // Now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to indicate that the end of the file has been reached
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
         " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
         //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
         //" file=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122360/html-and-php-mail-application-not-sending/20122624#20122624

Comment: You've got code missing. How do you use those variables? You've got multipart headers there (which is good), but how are you combining your HTML with the other parts?

Comment: @Quentin kindly see my updated question I added all the header I used. My message in email is messed up .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the Content-Type to text/html and see, if it works.

But if you want to send complex emails (for example with attachments or with HTML!) then you can just use the [phpmailer-class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

It is very easy to implement and to use. You can take a look at the examples given in the examples folder. Then you can send HTML-Mails in a very simple way.